# Increment Text Column on Conflict "cool name" --> "cool name 1"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a unique column `display_name` on a table. When inserting a new row, I would like to do the following `ON CONFLICT (display_name)`: append a number to the `display_name` value such that it is now unique.

e.g. in postgres 10,

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  display_name text UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO some_table (display_name) VALUES ('cool name');

INSERT INTO some_table (display_name) VALUES ('cool name')
  ON CONFLICT (display_name) ....
  -- 'cool name' is a duplicate here, can I somehow increment a suffix
  -- here until it is a unique value (like 'cool name 1')?
```

Comment: Make it possible/easy to assist you: [mcve]

Comment: @jarlh added what I _think_ is an mre? Not totally sure how to do it for sql

Comment: Since the id is unique, even when display_name is not, you could consider concatenating the two?

Comment: @Eli I don't think the ID will be available at that point, bc the row has not been created yet. Is it available in the "on conflict" block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` will update the existing row, not the new row to be inserted. What you need to do is to select the value-to-be-inserted dynamically so that it doesn't already exist:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (display_name)
SELECT name
FROM generate_series(0, 1000) num,
LATERAL (SELECT 'cool name' || CASE WHEN num = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' ' || num END AS name) AS t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM some_table WHERE display_name = name)
ORDER BY num
LIMIT 1;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=ed8ef02622fa4c60584680abf200d196))</sup>
This will try up to 1000 suffixes until it gives up.

Comment: Cool idea, I like this.

Comment: Any performance  overhead that can  be present?

Comment: @MithunTheertha Should be fine if you have an index on `display_name`

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible to insert rows in `ON CONFLICT` clause (you can only update an existing row), so the construct cannot be used. Use plpgsql, e.g.

```
do $$
declare new_str text := 'cool name';
begin   
    insert into some_table (display_name)
    values (new_str);
exception when unique_violation then
    insert into some_table (display_name)
    select format('%s %s',
        new_str,
        (select coalesce(nullif(regexp_replace(display_name, '^.*?(\d+)$', '\1'), display_name), '0')::int+ 1
        from some_table
        where left(display_name, length(new_str)) = new_str
        order by 1 desc
        limit 1)
    );
end $$;
```

Live demo in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=4f387d0111607505c64bee3a24d34db3)

Comment: What your essentially is just modifying the data randomly. You could accomplish the same by generating a random number. But if you are just going the change the data to fit the constraint, maybe you need to rethink the constraint.  If it's actually required your process is violating the reason it exists, it it's not required then remove it.

Comment: @Belayer - There is nothing random in my solution. Are you sure you are commenting on the right answer?

Comment: @Avocado - I have updated the answer to correct a small mistake.

Comment: It's random not because you don't have a pattern, it's random because it doesn't matter what's added. Anything at all would suffice what you want. The point is why have the constraint if it doesn't have any business meaning.

Comment: Not sure this has the expected result [when some user intentionally uses a name ending in a large number](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=8002e3bc9fe3c5dd300b4564b8cc1c94)

Comment: @Belayer - You should probably address the author of the question.